# Logging module not working with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am having issues with the standard logging module. If I open a python2.7 shell and import logging everything works fine:

```
$ python
>>> import logging
>>>
```

But if I open a python3.4 shell and import logging I get the following error:

```
$ python3.4
>>> import logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2222, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2164, in _find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1940, in find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1916, in _get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1897, in _legacy_get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 863, in spec_from_loader
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 904, in spec_from_file_location
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/logging-0.4.9.6-py3.4.egg/logging/__init__.py", line 618
raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what the problem is and can't seem to find anyone else who has had the same issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You seem to have installed a third party library called `logging` in your Python 3 environment, which is hiding the standard library version, and one of its files has a typo.

Comment: It's not so much a typo than that it's Python 2 syntax. But yes, that's not the (location of) the built-in logging module.

Comment: Thank you both! I deleted `logging-0.4.9.6-py3.4.egg` from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/` and now logging is working in both python2 and python3.

Answer (score 42):

logging module is by default there in Python 3 environment .No need to import  it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's definitely a correct answer

Comment: I was trying to add `logging==0.4.9.6` in the requirements file of my gfunc xD, and it didn't even show me the error in the logs.

Answer (score 7):

I stupidly created a file called **logging.py** to try out some log features. Then when trying the code below, it is effectively referring to itself and can't find the debug method.

```
import logging

logging.debug("Debug message")
```

Changing my file name to **logtest.py** fixed the problem.

Comment: I felt like a clown when I read this and realized that was my issue too. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the previous install of a logging library under an older Python version.

```
pip3 uninstall logging
```

fixed it for me.