# Unable to install logging module (Python)

Tags: python, logging, pip, python-logging

I'm trying to install the logging module for Python 3.4. I'm using pip3 install logging. Both times I run into a SyntaxError at line 618 of the `__init__` method: `"raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\".`

Someone posted the same question as me, and solved their problem by deleting an interfering third party library called logging: [Logging module not working with Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386469/logging-module-not-working-with-python3).

But I have no such library already installed in my site-packages directory.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) is part of the Python standard library, and has been since version 2.3. It's available as soon as you install Python. You don't need to `pip install` anything...

Comment: none of the standard libraries get installed when using virtualenv for python3. So how would one install logging into a virtualenv?

Comment: @wesm of course they do. Python wouldn't function without the stdlib. The files may not be copied into your virtualenv from the system location, but they're still available for use.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install the `logging` module separately.

`logging` is a standard Python module, and it comes with the Python installation.

You just need to use `import logging` in your python code.